# Сохранение пропорций при изменении размеров окна

Tags: java, swing

Можно ли в SWING сделать так, что бы при изменении размеров окна мышкой, оно сохраняло заданные пропорции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Надо озаботиться слушателем `ComponentListener` и ловить событие:

```
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
    Rectangle r = event.getComponent().getBounds();
    r.height=(int )aspectRatio*r.width; //пересчет новой высоты с учетом нужной вам aspectRatio
    event.getComponent().setBounds(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
}
```

`float aspectRatio` - надо заранее сохранить во время создания окна в членах класса